# Flutter video_player plugin - VideoPlayerController.seekTo

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and I'm using flutter video_player plugin to play videos. After I capture a video file (using camera plugin), I'd like to start video playback 1 second into the video (essentially to skip the first second). I tried using .seekTo and passed it a Duration but it returned the following error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter '_duration' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: _duration
```

The API reference seemed straightforward enough but it's not like Duration.  Here's my code and thanks in advance!

```
Future<void> _startVideoPlayer() async {

    videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(File(videoPath));

    videoPlayerController.setVolume(1.0);
    videoPlayerController.setLooping(true);
    videoPlayerController.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 1));
    await videoPlayerController.initialize();
    await videoPlayerController.play();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `await videoPlayerController.initialize();` before seeking?

Comment: I just did per the response below and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize first then do seekTo and play 
code snippet

```
_videoPlayerController1..initialize().then((_){
                      setState(() {
                        _videoPlayerController1.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 3));
                        _videoPlayerController1.play();
                      });
                    });
```

demo skip 3 seconds

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:chewie/src/chewie_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ChewieDemo(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class ChewieDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  ChewieDemo({this.title = 'Chewie Demo'});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ChewieDemoState();
  }
}

class _ChewieDemoState extends State<ChewieDemo> {
  TargetPlatform _platform;
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController1;
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController2;
  ChewieController _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _videoPlayerController1 = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4');
    _videoPlayerController2 = VideoPlayerController.asset(
        'assets/videos/sample.mp4');
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
      aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
      autoPlay: false,
      looping: true,
      // Try playing around with some of these other options:

      // showControls: false,
      // materialProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(
      //   playedColor: Colors.red,
      //   handleColor: Colors.blue,
      //   backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      //   bufferedColor: Colors.lightGreen,
      // ),
      // placeholder: Container(
      //   color: Colors.grey,
      // ),
      // autoInitialize: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController1.dispose();
    _videoPlayerController2.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: widget.title,
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        platform: _platform ?? Theme.of(context).platform,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: Chewie(
                  controller: _chewieController,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _chewieController.enterFullScreen();
              },
              child: Text('Fullscreen'),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _chewieController.dispose();
                        /*_videoPlayerController2.pause();
                        _videoPlayerController2.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 0));*/

                        _chewieController = ChewieController(
                          videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
                          aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                          autoPlay: false,
                          looping: true,
                        );

                        _videoPlayerController1..initialize().then((_){
                          setState(() {
                            _videoPlayerController1.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 3));
                            _videoPlayerController1.play();
                          });
                        });

                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      child: Text("Seek To"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _chewieController.dispose();
                        _videoPlayerController2.pause();
                        _videoPlayerController2.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 0));
                        _chewieController = ChewieController(
                          videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
                          aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                          autoPlay: true,
                          looping: true,
                        );
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      child: Text("Video 1"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _chewieController.dispose();
                        _videoPlayerController1.pause();
                        _videoPlayerController1.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 0));
                        _chewieController = ChewieController(
                          videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController2,
                          aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                          autoPlay: true,
                          looping: true,
                        );
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                      child: Text("Video 2"),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _platform = TargetPlatform.android;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      child: Text("Android controls"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _platform = TargetPlatform.iOS;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                      child: Text("iOS controls"),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you! I have a follow up question: I have .setLooping = true. When the video begins, it starts at my desired .seekTo value. However, when it loops, the loop begins in the original start of the video, not the .seekTo value (which is what I prefer). Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You can check video isEnd with https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21929 and seek again. or post another question. maybe there is good way.